# Accepting multiple values for a filter using the datagrid gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datagrid, rubygems

Could someone please post the proper syntax for setting up a `filter()` in datagrid to work with multiple values including the `column()` setup?

My use case is that I want to filter by distance from a certain origin. I am able to filter by an origin but I have to hard code in the distance. I would like to be able to pass "New York, NY" and "25" to the filter to give me all the results within 25 miles of New York, NY.

You don't have to show the actual logic just how to successfully get the two variables passed into the code block.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
filter(:user_location, :string, :header => "Location", :multiple=>true) do |value|

origin = value[0]
distance = value[1]

end
```

When you setup the filter this way the form field is generated with `[]` automatically populating it. In order to pass multiple values it seems you need to enter them inside of the brackets, separated by commas.  ie `["New York, NY", "25"]`.  This really needs to be worked out better. When you submit the form the filtering is performed but then the field is populated with `["[\"New York, NY\", \"25\"]"]`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest slightly different thing. No need to concatenate two things into one:

```
filter(:user_location, :string, header: 'Location') do |value, model, grid|
  origin = value
  distance = grid.radius
  ...
end

filter(:radium, :enum, select: [5,10,15,20,25], dummy: true) 
  # can be integer instead of enum
```